# Prove: if $ax^2-bx+c$ and $dx^3-bx+c$ have a common factor, then $a^3-abd+cd^2=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Prove: if $ax^2-bx+c$ and $dx^3-bx+c$ have a common factor, then $a^3-abd+cd^2=0$.

Not really sure how to proceed. I know that first I have to find the common factor. I guess it is $x-c$ because both expressions end with the constant $c$. Then plug in $x=c$ to get $ac^2-bc+c=0, c^3d-bc+c=0$. Hence:

$ac^2=c(b-1) $

$c^3d=c(b-1)$

$ac^2=c^3d \Rightarrow a =cd $

Plug into the original third expression:

$(cd)^3-(cd)bd+cd^2=0 \Rightarrow c^3d^3-bcd^2+cd^2=0 \Rightarrow c^3d^3=cd^2(b-1) \Rightarrow c^2d=b-1$

This is greatly simplified, but it doesn't prove it is equal to $0$. I think it would be helpful to know the proper way to first find the common factor instead of just guessing. Thanks!

Comment: Of course the common factor need not be $x-c$. You know both the factors of the quadratic because of the quadratic formula, so the common factor must be equal to $x -$ (one of those roots). Nevertheless, something tells me you shouldn't need the explicit value of the root, but instead should play with the (three) equalities $ax^2-bx+c=dx^3-bx+c=0$ (for some fixed value of $x$ which is the root) to get the answer, by eliminating the root.

Comment: Another thing : you need to assume that $c \neq 0$, otherwise $0$ will always be a common root of both sides (and $x$ a common factor), so the question's conclusion will be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $t$ be the common root. Then

$dt^3-bt+c=at^2-bt+c$

$dt^3-at^2=0$

$t^2(dt-a)=0$

$t=0$ or $t=\frac{a}{d}$

But $t=0$ is not a common root of the equations for $c\neq 0$. If $c=0$, $t$ is a common root but it does not satisfy the condition of the question.

For $t=\frac{a}{d}$

$a (\frac{a}{d})^2-b(\frac{a}{d})+c=0$

$a^3-abd+cd^2=0$.

Comment: $t=0$ is not a common root when $c \neq 0$. Otherwise, it is a common root and the conclusion of the question doesn't hold, so that needs to be mentioned.

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer : I mentioned all the details.

Comment: Thanks, I've voted up.

Answer (score 2):

The question is

> Prove: if $ax^2-bx+c$ and $dx^3-bx+c$ have a common factor, then $a^3-abd+cd^2=0$.

The common factor can be of degree $0, 1,$ or $2$. If the common factor
is of degree $0$, then it divides $a, b, c, d$ but otherwise there is no
constraint on them. Thus, we assume it is of degree greater than zero.
If $\,c=0\,$ then the polynomials have a common factor of $\,x\,$ and
$\,a, b, d\,$ otherwise have no constraint. Thus, we assume further that
$\,c\ne 0.$

Compute the linear combination of the two polynomials

$$a(dx^3-bx+c)-dx(ax^2-bx+c) = (dx-a)(bx-c). \tag1 $$

Any common factor of the two given polynomials must divide any linear
combination of them and hence the product of the two linear factors.
Assuming the common factor is quadratic, then from equation $(1)$ we must
have (where $u\ne 0$)

$$ u(ax^2-bx+c) = uax^2 -ubx +uc = (dx-a)(bx-c) = bdx^2 -(ab+cd)x +ac. $$

Equating the constant term implies $\,u=a.\,$ Now equating the first degree
term implies $\,d=0\,$ which implies $\,a=0\,$ and hence $\,u=0\,$ which
contradicts $\,u\ne 0.\,$ Thus, the common factor must be linear.

Again, from equation $(1)$ the linear factor must divide $\,(dx-a)\,$ or
$\,(bx-c).\,$ Assume the second case then (where $\,u\ne 0$)

$$ ax^2-bx+c = (bx-c)(ux-v) = bux^2 -(cu+bv)x + cv. $$

Again, this implies that $\,a=bu,\,$ and $\,v=1\,$ since $\,c\ne 0.\,$
But now, the degree $1$ term implies that $\,cu=0\,$ which contradicts
both $\,c\ne 0\,$ and $\,u\ne 0.\,$

So, assume the first case then (where $\,du\ne 0$)

$$ ax^2-bx+c = (dx-a)(ux-v) = dux^2 -(au+dv)x + av. $$

Equating the degree $0$ and $2$ terms to zero implies that
$\,a = du, c = av.\,$ Equating the degree $1$ term to zero
implies that $\, du^2 + dv - b = 0.\,$ Now substitute the
values of $\,a,c\,$ in terms of $\,d,u,v\,$ into the condition

$$ a^3 - abd + cd^2 = ud^2(du^2 + dv - b) $$

which now equates to zero.

The result just proven is this:

**Theorem**: Given two polynomials with real coefficients $\,ax^2-bx+c\,$
and $\,dx^3-bx+c.\,$ Assuming $\,c\ne 0,\,$ if they have have a common
linear factor, then $a^3-abd+cd^2=0$.